# Microphone function in python doesnot stop listening

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a chatbot in python 3. I used the function Microphone to record my voice. If i plugin my earphone then it works perfectly. But without earphone if i say something, it takes the input (listens to me) but doesnot stop listening till i plugin my earphone and say something. Why does not it stop listening to me without earphone?
Here is my code snippet-

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening....")
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

I want the chatbot to stop listening and start executing within 1 second gap when i have not connected earphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the prompt never returns, your microphone is most likely picking up too much ambient noise. To handle ambient noise, you’ll need to use the adjust_for_ambient_noise() method of the Recognizer class.

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening....")
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) # This filters noise
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

I researched for hours and found the solution for my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
!pip install -c conda-forge google-api-python-client
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold = 2500
#Input your speech by listen(_)
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Say Something:!')
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print('Done!')

try:
   print("You said: \n" + r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'hi-IN'))
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Above I tried and worked in my local.
Please explain a bit more about your query. What i understand is it is working fine with microphone and not working well when you speaking without microphone. It might be due to sr.Microphone() as a source.

You may try with using the audio file as the audio source  -

```
from os import path
AUDIO_FILE = "/Path of audio file.....wav"
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file
```

Comment: Thanks @Nitesh, but I found solution to my question and i posted it here. Might be your solution be helpful in future for other learners, don't delete it.